Editing points of a USplineComponent component in the editor does not trigger the OnConstruction event in the owner actor for UE 5.4.1 version
Steps to Reproduce:
Create a C++ actor
Create a USplineComponent property
UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, Category = “SplineCraft”)
USplineComponent* SplineComponent;

2.1 Constructor & event OnConstruction
ASplineCraftLiteActor::ASplineCraftLiteActor()
{
PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

DefaultRootComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("DefaultRootComponent"));
SetRootComponent(DefaultRootComponent);

SplineComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USplineComponent>(TEXT("SplineComponent"));
SplineComponent->SetupAttachment(DefaultRootComponent);
}

void ASplineCraftLiteActor::OnConstruction(const FTransform& Transform)
{
Super::OnConstruction(Transform);

BuildCraft();
}

Create a BP that derives from the actor
Place the actor on the level. Start adding or moving spline points.
Expected Result:
The OnConstruct event in the owner actor must be called
Short video
https://mega.nz/file/U78AyAAT#dexqHSvO6GhjacFTSDcH8m6_KfjMZp4jmRRzc5L-uuI
Actual Result:
The OnConstruct event is not called in the owner actor.
Short video
https://mega.nz/file/xjUUwTCZ#ALAo044hlnwiUatjIRop8l0dOpLv7bWEnnSYGKNyCsU
